# How to write a correct sql query which do not return duplicated result?

Tags: sql

I have multiple tables and I joined them incorrectly or I am missing something.

Table joins looks this:

```
SELECT Item.*, Category.*, SubCategory.*, Location.*, Brand.*, ItmCondition.*, User.*, Image.*
FROM Item
JOIN Category ON Item.Category_Id = Category.Category_Id
JOIN SubCategory ON Item.SubCategory_Id = SubCategory.SubCategory_Id
JOIN Location ON Item.Location_Id = Location.Location_Id
JOIN Brand ON Item.Brand_Id = Brand.Brand_Id
JOIN ItmCondition ON Item.Condition_Id = ItmCondition.Condition_Id
JOIN User ON Item.User_Id = User.User_Id
JOIN Image ON Item.Item_Id = Image.Item_Id
WHERE Item.Category_Id =".$_GET['ctgId'];
```

Each item in Item table has one or more related image/s in Image table. I want to fetch the first image as a thumbnail for each Item even tho each Item can have one or multiple images in Image table. with the above query I get duplicated Items for each Images related to it. I’m pretty new to this and I hope you understand what I’m trying to say!

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data, the result you get for it, and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: which do not return duplicated result? -> join on unique keys, otherwise you'll get cartesian product of the rows

Comment: you've explained what you need to do in your question; you *know* you have more than 1 image for an `Item` so joining to `Image` will give you `n` rows per `Item` - this is hopefully obvious. If you want "the first image" only then you need to *do that before joining* or use a *lateral join* - dependent on your specific DBMS which appears a secret.

Comment: thanks all for the reply, Stu you get my idea. I know the result is correct based on the query I feed but I don't know which is a proper way to return only the first image. The thing is I'm newby and I would like to see how to do it in actual example!